# Rails/PHP Coexistence

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, migration

I currently have an application that is built w/ PHP/MySQL using the [Laravel Framework](http://laravel.com). I want to migrate this application over to [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) but I total teardown/rebuild is not feasible. I am wondering how easily it would be to have a PHP application and a Rails application coexisting together and slowly migrating the code over.

Has anyone out there attempted this? If so, what are some noteworthy things that might be of use to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that comes to my mind that would stop you from doing this. As long as you are ensuring consistency in your database all the time it should not be a problem.

The most challenging task from my experience is to work around conventions in Rails, the naming of tables and columns for example. This is needed if you want to keep the database schema and it doesn't fit accidentally.